# How to launch this python GUI app without having a console in the background?

Tags: python

I have this python script named `clock.py`.

Here is the source code.

```
# Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-create-a-digital-clock-using-tkinter/

# importing whole module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# importing strftime function to
# retrieve system's time
from time import strftime

# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Clock')


# This function is used to
# display time on the label

def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
    lbl.config(text=string)
    lbl.after(1000, time)


# Styling the label widget so that clock
# will look more attractive
lbl = Label(root, font=('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
            background='purple',
            foreground='white')

# Placing clock at the centre
# of the tkinter window
lbl.pack(anchor='center')
time()

mainloop()
```

I place this python script as a short-cut on Windows. When I double-click on the short-cut icon, the python tkinter app will launch with a GUI but a console will also be launched. This console is redundant.

How can I launch this python script without launching the console? Modify the code or through some Windows settings?

[image]

I am using Windows 11.

Comment: Name your script `clock.pyw`, instead of `.py`.

Comment: thanks. That's the answer. I put your comment as the answer and credited it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the file as pyw and use pythonw for your Link, if you only want the tkinker window without a console shell window as well

```
pythonw.exe D:\test.pyw
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments provided the answer to my question. The credit goes to @jasonharper https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper

I put the solution here as reference.

**Name your script clock.pyw, instead of .py**

I did some research and found out the difference between .pyw and .py. It explains why .pyw works in my context.

The difference between a Python script with a file extension ".py" and ".pyw" is as follows:

".py" extension: When a Python script has a ".py" extension, it is typically executed using the Python interpreter, which opens a console window to display the output and interact with the user. This is useful for scripts that require user input or produce text-based output.

".pyw" extension: On the other hand, when a Python script has a ".pyw" extension, it is executed using the Pythonw interpreter. The "w" in "pythonw" stands for "windowed". Unlike the regular Python interpreter, Pythonw does not open a console window when running the script. Instead, it launches the script in the background and displays the graphical user interface (GUI) associated with the script, if any. This is particularly useful for GUI-based applications where a console window is not needed or desired.

**Conclusion: use .pyw for python scripts with GUI. Use .py for console-based python scripts.**